# Starting up dependent services in Jenkins

Tags: docker, jenkins

Our test suite relies on a number of subsidiary services being present - database, message queue, redis, and so on. I would like to set up a Jenkins build that spins up all the correct services (docker containers, most likely) and then runs the correct tests, followed by some other steps.

Can someone point me to a good example for doing such a thing? I've seen a plug-in for mongo, and some general guides on spinning up agents, but their relationship to what I'm trying to do is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to use the [JenkinsCI Kubernetes plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-plugin) and [jenkinsCI Kubernetes pipeline plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-pipeline-plugin): they will allow you to

- launch docker slaves automatically,
- with [container group support](https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-plugin/blob/ec7d74f8782941d2b146193ebb14ae6ef5da9a46/README.md#container-group-support) through podTemplate and `containerTemplate`.